# Pymongo: I would like to update first and last field of my document by using $min and $max after $push/$pop operation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm ingesting stock ticker price into a mongodb document every ~5 minutes using pymongo. The approach is the same of timeseries sensors in IOT. My collection is initialized with data from API.

In the document I have two arrays:

1. 'date' --> where I'm storing the timestamp.
2. 'quote' --> where I'm storing the price.

Obviously the item quote[0] is the ticker's price at date[0]. This is the logic.

I have two other important fields in the document:

1. 'first'--> which represents the first date in the array
2. 'last' --> which represents the last date in the array.

Both value are initialized after the first query.

Every time a new value is queried to the API i would like to ingest the value and the date in my array, but since this collection describes the DAILY price, i would like to remove the first element in the array (both for quote and date).

I don't know how to deal with first and last element. Let's make an example:

```
date = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # each element is actually a timestamp
quote = [10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.1, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.8, 10,9, 10.1]
first = 0
last = 10
```

Whenever a new quote arrives i would like to POP the first element in both the array, PUSH the new value [date and quote], and UPDATE first and last FIELD of my document.

If the new item is {date: 11, quote: 10.5}, I expect:

```
date = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, **11**] # each element is actually a timestamp
quote = [10.2, 10.3, 10.1, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.8, 10,9, 10.1, **10,5**]
first = **1**
last = **11**
```

This what I produced... obviously it doesn't work.

```
    for item in data:
        collection.update({'ticker': item['ticker']}, {"$set": item}, upsert=True)
        first_date = collection1.find({'ticker': item['ticker']}, {'_id':0, 'first':1})
        last_date = collection1.find({'ticker': item['ticker']}, {'_id':0, 'last':1})
        print(last_date[0]['last'])
        print(first_date[0]['first'])
        collection1.update_many(
                {'ticker': item['ticker']},
                {
                    '$pop':{
                        'date':-1,
                        'quote':-1
                    }})
        collection1.update_many(
            {'ticker': item['ticker']},
            {
                '$push':{
                    'date': item['marketTime']['date'],  
                    'quote': item['price'],
                },
                # '$min' : {'first' : '$date'},
                # '$max' : {'last': '$date},
                '$inc': {'added_samples': 1}
                
            }, upsert=True)
```

The problem is that first and last are updated with '$date', actually only first, because 'last' remains the one initialized.

I hope my explanation of the situation is clear, here to learn how to deal with those type of situation.

Please don't take into account collection, it is my quotes collection where I update every 5 minutes the ticker information. The "problem" is about collection1.

Comment: Can you add a before and after - i.e. what you expect to happen.

Comment: Edited. Let me know if it is clear.